# Sinatra Inline Template Not Being Called

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have verified that `Merchant.find_all` is correctly returning an enumerator with many elements.  However, when I run the following code I get a blank page.  Why is the inline template not being call repeatedly and outputting "hello" a bunch of times?

```rb
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/reloader'
require 'sequel'
require_relative 'config/init'
require_relative 'merchant'

get '/' do
  Merchant.find_all.each do |m|
    erb :layout
  end
  ""
end

__END__

@@ layout
hello
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning an empty string from the route block. Return the erb result. If you actually want to render that view multiple times, then save the result of each `erb` into a string buffer and return that.

```
get '/' do
  result = ''
  Merchant.find_all.each do |m|
    result += erb(:layout)
  end
  result
end
```

I've never actually tried this, but I think it would work...